# MVC error al pasar datos del modelo entre las vistas

Tags: mvc

estoy desarrollando una app que para iniciar, debe pedir al usuario unos datos para auenticarse (usuario y password) pero en pantallas diferentes, ya que se trata de un totem (sin teclado ni mouse) y en cada pantalla despliega un teclado virtual, el cual es alfabetico para el usuario, y numerico para la password.

pues bien, en ese contexto, tengo un controlador MVC C#, que tiene un index, que es la pantalla de presentacion, y despues 2 vistas mas, una para el usuario, y otra para la password.
en resumen, esto funciona bien, ya que en cada pantalla rescato los datos (usuario y password) y se los paso a un modelo definido de la siguiente manera:

```
    public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    { }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre Usuario")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

el problema, es que al momento de ir al proceso de autenticacion (definido en una capa de negocios), la variable UserName, se pierde luego de que rescato la password.

aca esta el controller que tengo implementado:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    public ActionResult Index() // pantalla de inicio
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult IngresaUsuario() 
    {
        return View();
    }



    public ActionResult IngresaPassword()
    {
        usuario.UserName = Request.Form["_usuario"];

        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult EvaluaAutenticacion()
    {

        usuario.Password = Request.Form["_password"];


        return RedirectToAction("SeleccionaPacientes");
    }
```

en el actionReslt EvaluaAutenticacion, solo tengo la password como dato, ya que el usuario quedo null

la pregunta es: como debo declarar la variable usuario ? , porque aunque la declare como public, igual se pierde el valor del usuario.

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los datos solo viven *dentro de la solicitud*, quiero decir que aunque declares variables de clase, su información *no* se mantiene cuando haces acciones distintas.

Prueba lo siguiente: modifica `IngresaPassword` y manda tu objeto a la vista:

```
public ActionResult IngresaPassword()
{
    usuario.UserName = Request.Form["_usuario"];

    return View(usuario);
}
```

y en la vista añade como primera línea (o después de los `@using` que tengas):

```
@model TuNamespace.Models.Usuario
```

y modifica tu `form` añadiendo un

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.UserName" name="_usuario">
```

de esta manera puedes obtener el dato en `EvaluaAutenticacion`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EvaluaAutenticacion()
{
    usuario.UserName = Request.Form["_usuario"];
    usuario.Password = Request.Form["_password"];
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("SeleccionaPacientes");
}
```

¿Ves ese `HttpPost` que está justo arriba de la acción? Indica el modo de llamar a la acción, `post`. Es recomendable que llames con `post` o `put` a las acciones que **manden** información al servidor; para hacerlo solo debes añadir `method="post"` a tu etiqueta `form` en la vista:

```
<form action="/Home/EvaluaAutenticacion" method="post">
```

Y como comentario final, no hagas autenticación en `Home`, crea un controlador específico para diferentes grupos de acciones, en este caso el control de usuarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion, implemente en parte lo que dices, combinandolo con variables de sesion. Saludos